# Spring boot project is spring boot test initialisation error

Tags: spring-boot

My spring boot project is showing build failure with the following error

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.examples.springbootdemo.SpringbootDemoApplicationTests
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.055 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.examples.springbootdemo.SpringbootDemoApplicationTests
initializationError(com.examples.springbootdemo.SpringbootDemoApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner not present
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example2</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hello</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-hello</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Kunwar your question is not enough explanatory!

Comment: Post your test class and and explain the entire problem.

Comment: Looks like a missing test-scoped runtime dependency. Please also add pom.xml/build.gradle/etc to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add JUnit dependency in your pom.

```
 <dependency> 
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version> 
</dependency>
```